# PixelSearch - alarm sounds even though color is not showing in 600 x 800. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: autohotkey

As soon as I run the below script the alarm sounds even though ffff00 is not showing in the 600 x 800 square. Does anything jump out as being incorrect?

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance,Force
CoordMode,Pixel,Screen

found=0
Gui,Add,Button,GSILENCE,Silence

colors=ffff00
Loop
{
Loop,Parse,colors,`,
{
PixelSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 600, 600, 800, 800, ffff00, Fast RGB
If (ErrorLevel=0)
{
  Gui,Show
  found=1
  Loop
  {
    SoundPlay,*0
    If found=0
      Break
    Sleep,1000
  }
} 
Sleep,10000
Send,{F5}
}
}

SILENCE:
found=0
Gui,Hide
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran your code un-edited, I experienced the same issues as you. It appears that the problem in your code is in the `PixelSearch` line. There are two issues there actually:

1. The first is that the `ColorID` must be a hexadecimal value, which,
   in your case, just means that you must add a `0x` in front of your
   current value. As you have it currently, AHK is looking at the value of a variable named "ffff00", which has no value assigned to it. I'm not sure why, but apparently this matches to everything (instead of nothing, as I would have expected).
2. The second issue is that you need an extra comma between the variation and
   mode or, in your case, between your color and `Fast RGB`. While I'm not sure if the "fast" part actually worked, the "RGB" part definitely didn't as it was matching to cyan instead of yellow.

Here is the corrected line, which made the script work for me:

```
PixelSearch , OutputVarX , OutputVarY , 600 , 600 , 800 , 800 , 0xffff00 ,, Fast RGB
```

Note that if you intend to loop through a series of colors, that you'll want to store them as 0x hexadecimal values (either as a delimited string as you have or as an array of actual hexadecimal values -- AHK appears to be lenient).

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to help. How do I mark this thread as solved?

Comment: No problemo! There is a check mark that you can click next to my answer.